# UIScrollview constraints for different devices

Tags: swift, xcode

Currently, I have the following codes to make UIScrollView work for iPhone that I have set it up in the main storyboard.

```
var images: [String] = ["image1", "image2"]
var frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    pageControl.numberOfPages = images.count
    for index in 0..<images.count {
        frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
        frame.size = scrollView.frame.size
        
        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        imgView.image = UIImage(named: images[index])
        self.scrollView.addSubview(imgView)
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(images.count)), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
    scrollView.delegate = self
}
```

I am trying to make a horizontal scrollview in xcode but when I run the project on iPad, the scrollview changes to the screen size but not the images. I looked up solutions online by adding views to the scroll view but it does not work. I am trying to make the images resize accordingly to the scrollview size.

Quick fact: Images are stored in Assets.xcassets.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!